# How do I access node on subnet from node on primary network?

Tags: router, bridge, wireless-bridge

[image: My network]]

I want to reach a node on the subnet, e.g. `192.168.2.239`, from a node on the primary, e.g. `192.168.1.2`.  Currently pinging from `192.168.1.2` to `192.168.2.239` gets no response. What do I need to set up in the definition of the bridge router?

Answer (score 0):

You might not be able to have multiple subnets on the LAN side of these routers, they may only take two subnets, the WAN and one for the LAN.  (unless perhaps one put DDWRT or Tomato on one of them, and not for bridge mode, but for additional router or VLAN switch functionality).

So if you then don't have multiple subnets on the LAN then  two options are

1. You could make them all `192.168.1.x`/`255.255.255.0`. So change the `192.168.2.x` addresses to `192.168.1.x`.
2. Or make the subnet `192.168.x.y`/`255.255.0.0`. Then you can keep both the `192.168.1.x` addresses and the `192.168.2.x` addresses.

And by the way, those routers AFAIK even in router mode don’t have an IP on each LAN port/interface. So I don’t know why your Linksys which you’ve written in your diagram as being in bridge mode, can have an IP on each.

If it was in router mode it’d have an IP on the LAN side to access its web interface, but that’s not associated with any particular LAN port. And if it was in bridge mode then it probably wouldn’t have an IP for a web interface at all.

From my experience—and maybe Linksys is an exception to what I’ve seen—but when these NAT routers are in bridge mode they don’t have any IP and have to be reset and go into router mode to access the web interface.

Comment: I tried the two proposed options: 1. (Changing to 192.168.1.x) The Netgear router no longer recognized the Linksys router as an attached device (strange). 2. (Changing subnet mask to 255.255.0.0) Didn't appear to change the behavior.

Comment: Incidentally, I installed DD-WRT v24-sp2 on the Linksys router - that's what allows me to have it run in bridge mode.

Comment: And just to clarify, the above configuration (2 subnets on the LAN side) does work at the basic level, i.e. all nodes can see and communicate with the internet.

Comment: @Andrew I wonder if maybe you need DDWRT or tomato on a router (not on a device to put it in bridge mode, but on a device as a router), in order to get support for multiple subnets LAN side. I am pretty sure netgear's basic range of routers don't support that, they have a buggy VLAN Switch router(the FV318) that would.  Some netgear devices support DDWRT check if your netgear supports it